# how to set Data context of command in itemcontrols in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding

how to set Data context of command in itemcontrols in wpf

```
<controls:ImageButton x:Name="CardEditButton" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=AutofillTab, Path=DataContext}"                                                                                    ImagePath="Media\Core\WhiteEditButton.png"  Height="24" Width="24"                                                                                    Command="{Binding EditCommand}"  Margin="0 0 40 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
</controls:ImageButton>
```

this command not working when add in itemcontrolTemplate

```
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cards, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinHeight="200" x:Name="CardsItemsControl">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="265" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="40"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Cursor="Hand" 
                                    Background="{Binding Model.Color,Converter={StaticResource CardColorToBrushConverter}}" Margin="16 12 16 0"
                                    Foreground="White" 
                                    Content="{Binding Name}" 
                                    x:Name="ItemButton" MouseLeave="ItemButton_MouseLeave" MouseEnter="ItemButton_MouseEnter">

                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate  TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid ClipToBounds="True" Name="TemplateGrid"  >
                                                <Rectangle Name="Rect" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Height="40"  />

                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <controls:AutoGrid Columns="Auto,*" >
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="8 8 0 8"></TextBlock>

                                                    </controls:AutoGrid>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <controls:ImageButton x:Name="ExtendButton" Visibility="Hidden"  ImagePath="Media\Core\InfoButton.png" ImageHeight="24" ImageWidth="24"  Click="Item_OnClick"  Margin="0 0 8 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                                </controls:ImageButton>
                                                <controls:ImageButton x:Name="CardEditButton" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=AutofillTab, Path=DataContext}"
                                                                                ImagePath="Media\Core\WhiteEditButton.png"  Height="24" Width="24"
                                                                                Command="{Binding EditCommand}"  Margin="0 0 40 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                </controls:ImageButton>

                                            </Grid>
                                            
                                        </ControlTemplate>

                                    </Button.Template>


                                </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Can you please be more precise on the exact thing you want to do. Explain the goal of your code so we can either answer the question or offer you an alternative to avoid you to keep locked on a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to bind the `DataContext` of the button, use a `RelativeSource` binding on the `Command` property and look for an ancestor that has the `DataContext` you need. In this case I'm guessing it might be the `ItemsControl`.

```
<controls:ImageButton x:Name="CardEditButton" 
    ...
    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
        Path=DataContext.EditCommand}" />
```